# sort string array using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I has a string array declare as below

```
string[][] data = new string[3][];
string[] name = new string[10];
string[] contact = new string[10];
string[] address = new string[10];
```

After i fill the data to name, address and contact, the address can be empty string in some data.  After that I assign it to string array data.

```
data[0] = name;
data[1] = contact;
data[2] = address
```

How I can sort the string array by name using LINQ.  I try
    data = data.orderby(y => y[0]).ToArray();

but this sort will change the sequence of the string array.  Suppose data[0] is store name but after sorting it become store address.
Any one has idea how can I sort the record?  Please help

Comment: This seems a bit complex for such a simple thing. Simply create a class/struct to hold your data and create an array out of that. It is far easier to sort and handle.

Comment: Use Data Array to List

Answer (score 28):

You can use this to sort the name array (which is stored at `data[0]`):

```
data[0] = data[0].OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

However, this will cause the data stored in the other arrays to loose any meaningful correlation to the name array (e.g. `name[3]` most likely will not match up with `contact[3]`). To avoid this,
I'd strongly recommend using a class to store this information:

```
class MyClass // TODO: come up with a better name
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

To declare the array, use:

```
MyClass[] data = new MyClass[10];
data[0] = new MyClass   // Populate first record
{
    Name = "...",
    Contact = "...",
    Address = "...",
};
```

And to sort the array:

```
data = data.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToArray();
```

Or this:

```
Array.Sort(data, (x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
```

The second option is more efficient as it rearranges the elements in place, and doesn't require allocating a new array to store the results.

Or alternatively, use a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6hkc2c4.aspx):

```
List<MyClass> data = new List<MyClass>(10);
data.Add(new MyClass   // Populate first record
{
    Name = "...",
    Contact = "...",
    Address = "...",
});
```

And to sort the list:

```
data.Sort((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
```

This will have similar performance to the `Array.Sort` method, however, it is a much better option if you need to be able to add or remove elements from your list dynamically.