# How to sort an array based on specific index

Tags: c#, arrays

I Have an array like below code :

```
    struct Book_Struct
    {
        public string Title;
        public string Auther;
        public int Date;
        public int ID;
    }

    static void Print(Book_Struct[] a, int b)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  Name of Book " + (i + 1) + " is : " + "\" " + a[i].Title + " \"");
            Console.WriteLine("Auther of Book " + (i + 1) + " is : " + "\" " + a[i].Auther + " \"");
            Console.WriteLine("  Date of Book " + (i + 1) + " is : " + "\" " + a[i].Date + " \"");
            Console.WriteLine("    ID of Book " + (i + 1) + " is : " + "\" " + a[i].ID + " \"");
            Console.WriteLine("\n---------------------------------\n");
        }
    }
```

I want sort this array based on for example Title of Books. How do i it?

Comment: As an aside, I would *strongly* recommend against using mutable structs and public fields. It looks like this should probably be a class with public *properties*... you should also look into .NET naming conventions.

Comment: Also after 7 years @JonSkeet no longer recommends duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304278/how-to-sort-an-array-containing-class-objects-by-a-property-value-of-a-class-ins (but it still relevant). You can find that recommendation in [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304278/how-to-sort-an-array-containing-class-objects-by-a-property-value-of-a-class-ins) that talks explicitly about arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzw8611x(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Array.Sort(a, (b1, b2) => b1.Title.CompareTo(b2.Title));
```

or LINQ:

```
a = a.OrderBy(book => book.Title).ToArray();
```

The latter needs to recreate the array.

As an aside,  use a class instead of a [mutable struct.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ's `OrderBy` to sort the array:

```
a = a.OrderBy(x => x.Title).ToArray();
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951687/sort-string-array-using-linq)